# Accessing global function inside js in html page on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to access a global function that I declare inside my main.js file and try to use it in the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
    <script>
    (function(){
      window.myFunction();
    })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my main.js file

```
(function(){
  window.myFunction = function(){
    alert(1);
  }
})();
```

This works on all browsers but IE9 and haven't tested other IE versions. What do you think I'm doing wrong? or is it something that has to do with IE?

Comment: I'd be making sure IE9 hasn't cached an older version of `main.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass window object like this in your main.js

```
(function(w){
  w.myFunction = function(){
    alert(1);
  }
})(window);
```

the variables after function keyword inside "()" is the alias of the passed parameter inside the function, while the variables inside "()" on the end of encapsulated function is the real variables being passed.

DEMO : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOgZdB - already tried in IE.

Another thing I think you can bind function to window directly, and you don't need to put it inside encapsulated function like:

```
   window.myFunction=function(){
      alert(1);
   }
```

in your main.js without encapsulating it.

Comment: This is not the case. If you notice, the calling of the function that is inside main.js is done OUTSIDE of that file (In the next script tag). In IE is like the window object for both script tags is different. If I do the call inside the same file it works properly.

Comment: It works fine for me, even in separate files like you do above, are you sure you referenced your js file correclty?

Comment: Another thing put that script tags inside headtag not in the body

Comment: I found the problem! It was actually another js file that was literally reassigning the window object reference by creating a copy of it lol.
It looks like the other browsers were protecting this from happening but no IE. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <body>
      <script src='main.js'></script>
      <script>
        window.myFunction();
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE 9, so I don't know it works or not. But tested in IE 11.

```
(function(window){
  window.myFunction = function(){
    alert(1);
  }
})(window);

(function(){
     window.myFunction();
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqsrpkpm/

Comment: thanks but no, passing the object window to the function didn't work.